# XML to Calc - starting file seems strange

Tags: android, xml, xslt

My apologies if this seems pretty basic.  This is my first time converting an xml file. The format of the xml file rendered by an Android app seems at odds with what I am seeing in tutorials on youtube or sources I am reading for importing to LibreOffice Calc.  Here is a sample of the data dumped from my phone's call log:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<!--File Created By Call Logs Backup & Restore v3.45 on 22/12/2014 11:27:17-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="calls.xsl"?>
<calls count="3">
  <call number="+15555555555" duration="46" date="1401396504704" type="1" readable_date="May 29, 2014 4:48:24 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
  <call number="+15555555555" duration="62" date="1401487115708" type="1" readable_date="May 30, 2014 5:58:35 PM" contact_name="ICE-In Case of Emergency" />
  <call number="+15555555555" duration="51" date="1401559219530" type="1" readable_date="May 31, 2014 2:00:19 PM" contact_name="ICE-In Case of Emergency" />
</calls>
```

From research I have done, to create an xslt transformation stylesheet the structure of that data has to be more like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<!--File Created By Call Logs Backup & Restore v3.45 on 22/12/2014 11:27:17-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="calls.xsl"?>
<calls count="3">
  <call>
    <number>+15555555555</number>
    <duration>46</duration>
    <date>1401396504704</date>
    <type>1</type>
    <readable_date>May 29, 2014 4:48:24 PM</readable_date>
    <contact_name>(Unknown)</contact_name>
  </call>
  <call>
    <number>+15555555555</number>
    <duration>62</duration>
    <date>1401487115708</date>
    <type>1</type>
    <readable_date>May 30, 2014 5:58:35 PM</readable_date>
    <contact_name>ICE-In Case of Emergency</contact_name>
  </call>
  <call>
    <number>+15555555555</number>
    <duration>51</duration>
    <date>1401559219530</date>
    <type>1</type>
    <readable_date>May 31, 2014 2:00:19 PM</readable_date>
    <contact_name>ICE-In Case of Emergency</contact_name>
  </call>
</calls>
```

Is there something I am missing for working with the xml file as it presently stands?  I attempted to get support for the author of the phone app which creates this xml file but no luck.  Do I have to edit the source to a more appropriate format like the second screenshot?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do not post code in images. Please edit your question, delete the images and post the code _as code_ - indented by four spaces.

Comment: I think I need guidance in escaping then.  I quoted using the prescribed method and nothing below the first line of the ?xml declaration would appear.

Comment: @dwlamb Paste the code into your question, select it and click the code sample `{ }` button.

Comment: "*From research I have done, to create an xslt transformation stylesheet the structure of that data has to be more like the second screenshot.*" The *only* requirement is that the source be a well-formed XML document. Of course, the transformation stylesheet must be custom-tailored to both the input and the output schema.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, but my question is: is the first sample of text considered well-formed xml data?  Or do I need to convert it to a format like the second text sample?

Comment: "*is the first sample of text considered well-formed xml data?*" Yes, it is well-formed. You can write a stylesheet that will take it as the input and transform it to whatever schema your target application requires.

Answer (score 0):

Both XML files that you posted are valid and well-formed. If the question is, *which* one is in the right format to be handled by the referenced `calls.xsl`, it's necessary to know the content of the `calls.xsl`. The *first* XML that you suppose to be in somehow unusual format is very common - every `call` node has several attributes - `number`, `duration`, `date` etc., while in the *second* XML every `call` node contains `number`, `duration`, `date` etc. as child nodes with the value as text.

Though not sure if this could be the `calls.xsl` that is used for the transformation, I found this:
http://android.riteshsahu.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/calls.xsl.
Just the relevant part from this template:

```
<xsl:for-each select="calls/call">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:if test="@type = 1">
        Incoming
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@type = 2">
        Outgoing
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@type = 3">
        Missed
      </xsl:if>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@contact_name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
    <br/>
      <xsl:value-of select="@readable_date"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For this template the first input XML is the correct version. When this calls.xsl is applied to your first XML, following result - as example only one row - is generated (added indentation for readability):

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Incoming            
  </td>
  <td>
    +15555555555
  </td>
  <td>
    ICE-In Case of Emergency
  </td>
  <td>
    1401559219530<br>May 31, 2014 2:00:19 PM
  </td>
  <td>
    51
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: "*The correct format of the input XML depends on the XSLT that will transform it*" That's a rather strange way to put it.  I would say it's the other way round: the correct XSLT is the one that fits the schema of the source XML (and of course the schema of the required output as well).

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's a rather strange question, too, without presenting the XSLT. As I understood the OP he's not sure about which is the right input XML for the XSLT that's missing in OP. My point was only that it's not possible to judge which is the right one as it depends on the XSLT that will handle it as both are valid. In addition, I added a link and a part of a calls.xsl which could be the one in question. If so, the first XML which OP thinks would 'seems to be at odds' is the appropriate input. Thanks for your concerns, I think about rephrasing it though I thought it'd be clear.